# What is the difference between impure and un-pure?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Algernon Blackwood’s *the Damned*, he describes Frances’ sketches from the POV of her brother:

> And the word that rose in my mind was not the gross description of "impure," but the more fundamental qualification—"un-pure”.

What is the difference between impure and un-pure? How should this be interpreted?

Comment: The author doesn't intend "un-pure" to be recognized as an existing word; he's trying to draw some semantic distinction in which "impure" is not the opposite of "pure," perhaps distinguishing the absence of purity from the presence of impurity. The [preceding paragraph](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Damned/Chapter_V) helps a bit, but it's still a bit abstruse and vague.

Comment: [Pure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pure) has many meanings but [impure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impure) has fewer and more specific.

Comment: You are impure if you get less than 100 un a Purity Teat. You are un-pure if you get 0.

Comment: Would the *Purity Teat* @Spencer refers to actually be a *Purity Test*?